# Laravel - Seeder para incrustat el "id" de otro modelo

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7, laravel-6

Tengo este Seeder para generar usuarios en mi sistema, de momento tengo los campos **name,email y password** , que los genero de forma random.

Pero me falta una propiedad que es company_id, que deberia hacer que el seeder mirase un "id" de la tabla companies random y lo colocase aquí, por más vueltas que le doy no se como hacerlo.

El código del seeder que tengo ahora es este

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class UserSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
            DB::table('users')->insert([
                'name' => Str::random(10),
                'email' => Str::random(10) . '@gmail.com',
                'password' => Hash::make('password'),
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Gracias

Comment: Se me ocurre que también hagas un random para crear las compañias, y en el seeder de User hagas un random para el campo `company_id` entre la cantidad de registros que tengas, ejemplo entre 1 y 9 que sería los Ids creados, claro tomando en cuenta que estás creando 10 registros en la tabla compañías.

Comment: Agrega lo que hagas intentado, cual punto de arranque nos sirve aunque tenga errores  para ayudarte

Comment: Si tienes una restricción que viene de la tabla companies no agregues un numero random, agrega un numero que ya estes sergur@ que está registrado  en al tabla companies y la tabla companies debe estar de  primera en tu lista de seeders a cargar antes que tu tabla usuarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para hacer eso tendrias que usar Factories,

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database-testing

te dejo el ejemplo de laravel docs

```
use Faker\Generator as Faker;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'email_verified_at' => now(),
        'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', // password
        'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
    ];
});
```

por lo que podes en los parametros agregar una function que cree otro modelo y de ahi del modelo creado le pedis el Id.
te dejo ejemplo:

```
return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'user' => function () {
            return \factory(User::class)->create()->id;
        },
```

Comment: Los factores no son necesarios, perfectamente puede usar al modelo y de forma aleatoria obtener el ID

Comment: Muchas gracias a los dos, ya lo conseguí. 1000 gracias